# URL Redirection with character - in HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite, character

I need to redirect multiple URLs with hyphens in them, through `.htaccess`.

Here is the current `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+).*$ /$1/ [R,L]
```

Here is an example of the URL format I am trying to redirect:

```
http://www.example.com/52346-3/
```

Should redirect to

```
http://www.example.com/52346/
```

I am new to `.htaccess` and just can't seem to get that last line quite right.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+).*$ /$1/ [R,L]
> ```

This redirect will need to go near the start of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the existing rewrites. You also need to remove the slash prefix from the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, otherwise it will never match in a directory (`.htaccess`) context.

So, assuming you simply want to strip everything after the first group of digits (including the hyphen), then try something like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+)- /$1/ [R,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

`\d` is a shorthand character class for `[0-9]`. `.*$` is the same as not including a trailing pattern at all.

I've also added the `L` flags - important for the second `RewriteRule`.

**UPDATE:** Added hyphen to the end of the `RewriteRule` *pattern* to explicitly match a hyphen (and to avoid a redirect loop).

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(\d+) /$1/ [R,L]` will cause an endless redirect loop.

Comment: @user82217 Testing on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ gives me the output http://www.example.com/52346/3/

Comment: So the code your provided seems to be doing some weird stuff. First, the site seems significantly slower in all browsers. Firefox is giving me an error stating "The page isn’t redirecting properly" on a URL of the above mentioned format. In safari a URL of the format `http://www.example.com/52346-3/` is redirecting to `http://www.example.com/<post title>/`

Comment: You would seem to have found a bug in the `madewithlove.be` tool (it is far from perfect unfortunately - I have submitted bug reports myself in the past). (It seems to be _copying_ everything after the match and appending it to the end of the _substitution_?!) If you want to satisfy that tool then it appears you can change the directive to read `RewriteRule ^(\d+)-.* /$1/ [R,L]` (ie. append `.*` on the end of the _pattern_) - however, _in the real world_ that sort of workaround is nonsense.

Comment: If you are getting different results in different browsers then make sure your browser cache is cleared. The above is a simple redirect, so it shouldn't "slow anything down", unless... you have a lot of resources referenced by URLs of this format and every request (ie. multiple requests per page view) are being redirected in this way, then yes, that would slow things down and quite possibly result in erratic browser behaviour (each browser has different limits).